# Corpora/stopwords not found when import nltk library

Tags: python, nltk

I trying to import the nltk package in python 2.7

```
  import nltk
  stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
  print(stopwords[:10])
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
Resource 'corpora/stopwords' not found.  Please use the NLTK
Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
```

So therefore I open my python termin and did the following:

```
import nltk  
nltk.download()
```

Which gives me:

```
showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
```

However this does not seem to stop. And running it again still gives me the same error. Any thoughts where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 168):

You are currently trying to download every item in nltk data, so this can take long. You can try downloading only the stopwords that you need:

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Or from command line (thanks to [Rafael Valero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048876/1916588)):

```sh
python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
```

---

### Reference:

- [Installing NLTK Data - Command line installation](https://www.nltk.org/data.html#command-line-installation)

Answer (score 46):

The some as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41640852/7127519) by  [Kurt Bourbaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916588/kurt-bourbaki) but in the command line:

```
python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do this in separately in console.
It will give you a result.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

I used jupyter console  when I faced this problem.

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 12):

if you get an SSL/Certificate error, run the following command.

This works by disabling SSL check!

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 5):

If your PC uses proxy for connectivity, then try this:

```
import nltk

nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **GPU runtime**, it will not give you any error.

The **same code** will work which you are using

```
import nltk
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
print(stopwords[:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the comment is quite late, but if it helps:

Although the `nltk.download('stopwords')` will do the job, there might be times when it won't work due to proxy issues if your organization has blocked it.

I found [**this github link**](https://gist.github.com/sebleier/554280) pretty handy, from where I can just pick up the list of words and integrate it manually in my project just as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

check what error you are getting --

```
python3 -m nltk.downloader stopwords
```

**Error :**

```
RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour


warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

Use the solution provided my @reshma2k

Answer (score 0):

```
showing info https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
```

If you are running this command in a jupyter notebook, it opens another window titled 'NLTK Downloader'. Once you go in that window, you can select the topics you want to download and then click on download button to start downloading.

Until you close the NLTK Downloader window, the cell in the Jupyter keeps on running.

Answer (score 0):

Installed the ntlk and imported the stopwords

```
!pip3 install nltk
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case after running

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

it did not work. The issue was wordnet.zip was unabale to unzip on its own so simple go to folder where`python3 -m textblob.download_corpora` this command installed package and unzip folder

```
cd ~
cd nltk_data/corpora/
unzip stopwords.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
words=stopwords.words('english')[0:20]
print(words)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).