# Run nltk.corpus data in python(jupyter) but shown this error So What should i do?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, anaconda

code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py:84, in 
 LazyCorpusLoader.__load(self)
       83 try:
  ---> 84     root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{zip_name}")
       85 except LookupError:

    File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py:583, in find(resource_name, paths)
       582 resource_not_found = f"\n{sep}\n{msg}\n{sep}\n"
   --> 583 raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
```

Getting this Error, I am trying the review product by replacing reviews with emoji and English short forms in python.

Comment: Look at this question and it's answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610543/corpora-stopwords-not-found-when-import-nltk-library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the mistake in the import nltk library .First you can download stopword nltk library then you can used the stopword in you program

Code

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download("stopwords") 
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stop
```