# Resource stopwords not found in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, nltk, python-3.7

I try to import the [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/) package in Python 3.7.9 with the following code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

---

```
english_stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

But when I run the above code, it shows me the following error:

```
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource stopwords not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load corpora/stopwords
```

I have followed what the error message and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41640852/16124033) say, adding `import nltk` and `nltk.download('stopwords')`. However, I still get the error message.

When I try `python -m nltk.downloader stopwords` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048876/16124033), it shows error `zsh: command not found: python`. I know I should change `python` to `python3`. So I need to run the command `python3 -m nltk.downloader stopwords`. When I run the command it shows the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)>
```

Is there a solution to the above error or the first error `Resource stopwords not found.` error? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssl.SSLError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41691327) (just adapt the answer for python 3.7)

Comment: @SuperStormer this question doesn't answer my question

Comment: You've ran the command provided? Then tried `python3 -m nltk.downloader stopwords` again?

Comment: @SuperStormer yes. I still get the same error when I run the provided command. When I try `python3 -m nltk.downloader stopwords` I get another error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:
`python -m nltk.downloader stopwords`.
If you are on windows10.

Comment: Please format the command as code, possibly on its own line. Right now, it's a bit ambiguous which parts of the text are and aren't part of the command.